# Interest calculator in Python. Find total sum and how much to pay each year

Tags: python, calculator

My goal is to find the total sum of the loan after five years, and also how much to pay each year.

My code so far:

```
years = 5

loan = 50000

interest = 0.05


for year in range(years):
    loan += loan * interest
    print(loan)
```

And is this the right way to find the annual payment per year?

```
sum = loan / years + loan * interest
```

Comment: If you're calculating compounded interest (A=Pe^rt), you might make use of exp() in the math library. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to do the calculations yourself, you could make use of [numpy_financial](https://pypi.org/project/numpy-financial/).

(NOTE: It is now recommended to use numpy-financial as the financial functions in numpy itself are being deprecated.

This to be installed with pip via `pip install numpy-financial`.

```
>>> import numpy_financial as npf
>>> npf.pmt(.05,5,-50000)
11548.739906413395
```

The above gives the annual payment.

So, for the first year, the amount of principal and interest paid would be:

interest = 50000*.05

principal_paid = 11548.74 - interest

Here is a small program that does that.

```
import numpy_financial as npf

rate = .05
principal = 50000
years = 5

annual_pay = npf.pmt(rate,years,-principal)

print('{}{:>10}{:>10}{:>10}'.format('year','interest','retired', 'balance'))

for yr in range(1,6):
    interest_to_pay = rate * principal
    retired_prin = annual_pay - interest_to_pay
    principal = principal - retired_prin
    print('{:>4}{:>10.2f}{:>10.2f}{:>10.2f}'
          .format(yr, interest_to_pay, retired_prin, principal))
```

This prints:

```
year  interest   retired   balance
   1   2500.00   9048.74  40951.26
   2   2047.56   9501.18  31450.08
   3   1572.50   9976.24  21473.85
   4   1073.69  10475.05  10998.80
   5    549.94  10998.80      0.00
```